# LinkedList Cycles in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I came across the following code for detecting LinkedList Cycles in JavaScript, but I'm unclear on why a "pause" variable is needed? Also, why does `fast` need to increment at twice the speed rather than just one ahead?

```
var fast = linkedList;
var slow = linkedList;
var pause = true;

while (fast = fast.next) {
  if (fast === slow) {
    return true;
  }
  if (!pause) {
    slow = slow.next;
  }
  pause = !pause
}
return false;
```

walk-through, assuming while condition is true up to 6 iterations:

```
//first iteration ----> pause is true
    //fast = linkedList.next
    //slow = linkedList
    //pause is now false.
//second iteration ----> pause is now false!
    //fast = linkedList.next.next
    //slow = linkedList.next
    //pause is now true
//third iteration ---> pause is now true.
    //fast = linkedList.next.next.next
    //slow = linkedList.next
    //pause is now false
//fourth iteration ----> pause is now false!
    //fast = linkedList.next.next.next.next
    //slow = linkedList.next.next
    //pause is now true
//fifth iteration ---> pause is true
    //fast = linkedList.next.next.next.next.next
    //slow = linkedList.next.next
//sixth iteration ---> pause is false
    //fast = linkedList.next.next.next.next.next.next
    //slow = linkedList.next.next.next
```

My original attempt at the problem is below, curious what was wrong with my original approach?

```
var slower = linkedList.value; // this is the head value
var faster = linkedList.next; //start faster one ahead

//if there is no next value or faster itself does not have a next value
if (!faster || !faster.next || !slower.next) {
  return false;

}
//if faster ever equals slower, then there are duplicates!
if (faster === slower || faster.next === slower || faster === faster.next ||
  slower === slower.next) {
  return true;
}
// keep advancing the pointers!
else {
  faster = faster.next.next;
  slower = slower.next;
}
```

Comment: `pause` makes sure that `slow` advances only once in two iterations.

Comment: not seeing what you are saying, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Initially both `slow` and `fast` will point to first element. In the next iteration, since `pause` is `true`, only `fast` is advanced. So, now `fast` will be pointing to second and `slow` will be pointing to first element respectively. In the next iteration, since `pause` is `false`, both `fast` and `slow` are advanced.

Comment: Got it. So I walked through the algorithm (code updated above) and it seems that ```fast``` moves at twice the speed of ```slow```, whereas in my implementation I was thinking it only had to be one ahead of ```slow```. do you know why ```fast``` needs to move at twice the speed instead of just one ahead?

Comment: @devdropper87, The distance between fast and slow determines the maximum length of the cycle it can detect.  If fast is always one ahead, then it will only ever detect cycles of length 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to leave it here in a few lines, and I'm going to put a reference where you can find it to practice; I hope it's helpful:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val) {
 *     this.val = val;
 *     this.next = null;
 * }
 */

/**
 * @param {ListNode} head
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var hasCycle = function (head) {
  let slow = head;
  let fast = head;
  while (fast && fast.next) {
    fast = fast.next.next;
    slow = slow.next;
    if (fast === slow) return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

training: [leetcode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/linked-list-cycle/)

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBTe7lFR3vc